# New column based on calculations on a specific value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column by making calculations on only certain values, depending on whether they match a certain string in a different column. For example,

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'currency': ['USD', 'PKR', 'PKR', 'USD'], 'amount': [1000, 34000, 40000, 560]})`

I want to create a new column in which I want to have the same PKR values, but I want USD values to multiply by 150.

Here is what I want,

`total = [150000, 34000, 40000, 84000]`

`df1['total'] = total`

Here I have manually multiplied the USD values. I am interested in getting the total column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set values by condition:

```
df1['total'] = np.where(df1['currency'] == 'USD', df1['amount'] * 150, df1['amount'])


print (df1)
  currency  amount   total
0      USD    1000  150000
1      PKR   34000   34000
2      PKR   40000   40000
3      USD     560   84000
```

Another idea especially if need multiple by multiple values by `currency` column create dictionary, use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), non matched values replace by `1` and last multiple column:

```
df1['total'] = df1['currency'].map({'USD':150}).fillna(1).mul(df1['amount'])
```

E.g. if want also multiple by `PKR` with `20`:

```
df1['total'] = df1['currency'].map({'USD':150, 'PKR':20}).fillna(1).mul(df1['amount'])
print (df1)
  currency  amount   total
0      USD    1000  150000
1      PKR   34000  680000
2      PKR   40000  800000
3      USD     560   84000
```